# firebase functions stopped working after iam

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Im trying to do something absurderlly simple but this whole IAM, Realtime Database, cloud functions misconfiguration are making me waste hours of work in something simple as a hello world.

I have an already populated database (over 300 items):

[image]

then i have the following function deployed to firebase cloud:

```
const actions = [];
const igDatabase = require('firebase-admin').initializeApp({
   serviceAccountId: 'actionkeeper@igibo-b0b27.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
}).database("https://igibo-b0b27.firebaseio.com/");

let lastMapRefresh = 0;
let lastUpdateFirebase = 0;

function refreshActions(afterRefresh) {
   console.log("refreshing actions");
   igDatabase.ref('actions/').orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(lastMapRefresh).once('value').then(function(data) {
      if (data != null && data.exists()) {
         let bef = actions.length;
         actions.length = 0;
         actions.push(data.val());

         lastMapRefresh = new Date().getTime();        
         afterRefresh();
      }
      console.log("actions refreshed before: " + bef + " now: " + actions.length);
   }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
   });
}

exports.decrementAction = (req, res) => {
refreshActions(function() {});
}
```

this function is simple reading a branch on database and populating an array... the purpose of the functio is more complex but im building it and testing slowly... and even this simple method is not working

the firebase rules for that node is:

```
{
   "rules":{

      "actions":{
         ".indexOn":[
            "timestamp"
         ],
         ".read":"auth != null",
         "$act":{
            "countdown":{
               ".write":"auth != null && data.val() - newData.val() == 1 && newData.val() >= 0"
            }
         }
      }
}
}
```

so ANYBODY logged can read

in the google IAM console i have
[image]

so the service account is supposed to have admin powers to database...

but running this function ALWAYS RETURN NULL `data`

why?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't appear to actually send a respond to the client.  Here's your function:

```
exports.decrementAction = (req, res) => {
    refreshActions(function() {});
}
```

Not once does it ever use `res` to send a response.  It's always going to time out after the default 60s, stuck waiting for you to call `res.send()` or something similar.

I suggest reviewing the documentation on [HTTP triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) to see how to send a response.  I imagine your (currently empty) callback function needs to do this, based on what `refreshFunctions` delivers to it.